# How can foreigners fly non-nano drones in India?

Tags: regulations, india

According to [some pages I found online](https://dronesforkids.in/drone-laws-india/), foreigners who want to fly non-Nano drones (drones over 250 grams) in India must lease their drone to an Indian entity who has authorizations from the Indian aviation regulator (DGCA).

How does this process work? Has anyone had experience with it? Can it be used only for commercial purposes, or also for recreational purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Micro drones are between 250 grams and 2 kilograms:

## Micro drones

These need registering, so therefore a foreigner will not be able to fly them. What you stated is for commercial purposes only. If you do want to fly commercially you will have to do some research before you travel, contacting an Indian entity and asking them to register it for you. This can be quite a hassle so I wouldn't do this unless it was really important.